# Process vim selection by Ruby and replace content

Tags: ruby, vim

How do I run a selection through a Ruby script and replace it with the last return value of that script?

For example I have this lines

```
12|22|33
```

and I want to double the digits

```
24|44|66
```

I don't know a *vim way* **(but I'd like to know if anyone can help)** but I'd know a Ruby way

```
# assuming the text is in variable "line"
line.split("|").map(&:to_i).map { |no| no*2 }.join("|")
```

Sure, I could write a Ruby script that takes arguments and call it with `:!my_script.rb %`, but I'd like to provide the Ruby code directly in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has an `-e` option that is usefull when providing short amounts of code:

```
:!ruby -e 'puts $_.split("|").map(&:to_i).map { |no| no*2 }.join("|") while gets'
```

If you only want to execute the code for a single line you can leave out the *while*-loop:

```
:!ruby -e 'puts gets.split("|").map(&:to_i).map { |no| no*2 }.join("|")'
```

When executing a terminal command the selected lines are send to it as standard input. `gets` will read from the standard input.

The [`Kernel#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) documentation:

> #### gets(sep=$/ [, getline_args]) → string or nil click to toggle source
>
> #### gets(limit [, getline_args]) → string or nil
>
> #### gets(sep, limit [, getline_args]) → string or nil
>
> Returns (**and assigns to `$_`**) the next line from the list of files in
>   `ARGV` (or `$*`), **or from standard input if no files are present on
>   the command line**. Returns `nil` at end of file. The optional
>   argument specifies the record separator. The separator is included
>   with the contents of each record. A separator of `nil` reads the
>   entire contents, and a zero-length separator reads the input one
>   paragraph at a time, where paragraphs are divided by two consecutive
>   newlines. If the first argument is an integer, or optional second
>   argument is given, the returning string would not be longer than the
>   given value in bytes. If multiple filenames are present in `ARGV`,
>   `gets(nil)` will read the contents one file at a time.
>
> ```
> ARGV << "testfile"
> print while gets
> ```
>
> *produces:*
>
> ```
> This is line one
> This is line two
> This is line three
> And so on...
> ```
>
> The style of programming using `$_` as an implicit parameter is
>   gradually losing favor in the Ruby community.

You can shorten the above by using the `-p` or `-n` flag, which wraps the code inside an `while gets` loop:

```
:!ruby -ne 'puts $_.split("|").map(&:to_i).map { |no| no*2 }.join("|")'
```

or

```
:!ruby -pe '$_ = $_.split("|").map(&:to_i).map { |no| no*2 }.join("|")'
```

From the `man ruby` page:

> ```
>      -n             Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your
>                     script, which makes it iterate over file name arguments
>                     somewhat like sed -n or awk.
>
>                           while gets
>                             ...
>                           end
>
>      -p             Acts mostly same as -n switch, but print the value of
>                     variable $_ at the each end of the loop.  For example:
>
>                           % echo matz | ruby -p -e '$_.tr! "a-z", "A-Z"'
>                           MATZ
> ```

Comment: thank you, my missing link was the `gets` method that reads the current line under your cursor

Comment: You can use `-p` flag and `$_` variable for that as well.

Comment: @Hauleth I forgot about them, since I don't use this mode often. But they shorten the code quite a bit. Updated the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that `!` as a normal command is an operator that prefills the range.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:h s/\\=` which allow you to do computations on match:

```
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)*2/g
```